# Search a partial word in key of C# dictionary and update its bool value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have declared a dictionary in the following way :

```
public static Dictionary<string,bool> Features {get;set;}
```

After this dictionary is populated it has following values :

```
**[Key],[Value]**
module1.add,true
module1.update,true
module1.delete,true
module1.save,true
module1.clear,true
module2.add,true
module2.update,true
module2.delete,true
module2.save,true
...
module10.add,true
module10.update,true
module10.delete,true
module10.save,true
```

After it is populated, i need to iterate over dictionary key and update dictionary values.

Ex : wherever i have .add and .delete in key, its value needs to be updated to false.

after update, it must look like this

```
module1.add,false
module1.update,true
module1.delete,false
module1.save,true
module1.clear,true
module2.add,false
module2.update,true
module2.delete,false
module2.save,true
...
module10.add,false
module10.update,true
module10.delete,false
module10.save,true
```

Let me know how to iterate through the dictionary and update the value in C#.
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I suppose it will be lot faster to find the answer than posting a question.

Comment: Your keys are clearly composited -- you have a noun (modules) and verb (add/ delete/etc), and so it's no wonder you're struggling a bit with implementation. 

I think overall it'd be better to split out the module and verb into separate dictionaries, so that you would have Features ["module1"]["add"] and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will get all the keys that end in .add or .delete and update their values to false.

```
Features.Keys.Where(v => v.EndsWith(".add") || v.EndsWith(".delete"))
    .ToList().ForEach(v => Features[v] = false);
```

---

Here it is without linq:

```
var targetFeatuers = new List<string>();
foreach (var feature in Features.Keys)
{
    if (feature.EndsWith(".add") || feature.EndsWith(".delete"))
    {
        targetFeatuers.Add(feature);
    }
}

foreach (var feature in targetFeatuers)
{
    Features[feature] = false;
}
```

Note that you have to create the separate list of keys to avoid modifying the collection as you enumerate it.

Comment: i cannot able to use .Where, i am using VS 2008. Is that the problem?

Comment: @VikasKunte Have you got `using System.Linq;` at the top of your class?

Comment: @Jon, any idea why this approach doesn't cause `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` error when Dennis's answer does?

Comment: @Manatherin : Thanks for that. The error went off. testing the above piece of code

Comment: @jon :Thanks a lot. It worked

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var item in Features) {
    if (item.Key.Contains("delete") || item.Key.Contains("add"))
        Features[item.Key] = false;
}
```

Comment: Would it not be slow, and deny the purpose of dictionary this way?

Comment: @Neolisk maybe, yes. Do you have better solution along the lines of OPs question?

Comment: @JonB thanks for the info. I didn't check it in the compiler. Just replace it with Features[item.Key] then.

Comment: Suggest a re-design perhaps. Cause clearly here the dictionary is not being used according to intended purpose.

Comment: Also - `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` cause by changing in the foreach

Comment: @Neolisk you're probably right, but that wouldn't answer OP's question anymore.

Comment: IMHO, no point in answering a question if it does not solve the problem. And yes, I agree it's hard to dig to what the original problem is, from the above question. :)

Answer (score -1):

This is how you update a value in your particular dictionary.

```
bool newValue = true;
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey("module10.add")) {
    myDictionary["module10.add"] = newValue;
}
```

This is how you loop over all the items in your dictionary.

```
foreach (string key in myDictionary.Keys) {
    myDictionary[key] = newValue;
}
```